# Writing from SQL Server table to file using BCP

Tags: sql-server, command-line, sqlbulkcopy

I just realized my caps was on from working in SQL Server, ha.

Anyways, Im trying to write from

**serverName.databaseName.databaseInstanceName.TableName**

to

**C:\FileName.xml**

using **bcp** and I want to write only columns **Col1** and **Col2**, could I get a little syntax help? I'm struggling over here.

Thanks,

Ted

Comment: I did google it but my search terms were off... I got some better info this time. I'll post my result for future SO reference once ive got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI for anyone else....

bcp "Select whatever from dbInstanceName.dbo.tableName"  quesryout C:\output.txt -e C:\errors.txt -c -T -S localhost\dbName

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an XML version of the format file the command is identical except we use the -x parameter.

```
bcp "SELECT col1, col2 FROM AdventureWorks.HumanResources.Department" format nul -c -x -f department.xml -T -S servername
```